# Collection view throws exception when scrolling and dragging a cell

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

My app displays a board with some cards, trying to implement D&D cards between columns.

To implement that it uses a collection view with scrolling horizontally, the collection view cells are representing the columns.

Each column is another collection view that scrolls vertically and cells are the cards.

I can do drag and drop with no issues between visible columns, but if I am trying to drag a card to a column outside the view, the view will scroll and I can see the column but on dropping, I got an exception:

```
*** Assertion failure in -[UICollectionView _validateScrollingTargetIndexPath:], UICollectionView.m:6485
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Attempted to scroll the collection view to an out-of-bounds item (0) when there are only 0 items in section 0.
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff203fbbb4 __exceptionPreprocess + 242
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff2019ebe7 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   Foundation                          0x00007fff20750c12 _userInfoForFileAndLine + 0
    3   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff2465de4b -[UICollectionView _validateScrollingTargetIndexPath:] + 405
    4   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff2465e290 -[UICollectionView _contentOffsetForScrollingToItemAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:] + 52
    5   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff2465ef51 -[UICollectionView _scrollToItemAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:] + 166
    6   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff246d1593 -[_UICollectionViewDragDestinationController _reorderingDisplayLinkDidTick] + 1800
    7   QuartzCore                          0x00007fff287c80a4 _ZN2CA7Display11DisplayLink14dispatch_itemsEyyy + 914
    8   QuartzCore                          0x00007fff288bf828 _ZL22display_timer_callbackP12__CFMachPortPvlS1_ + 393
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2033670d __CFMachPortPerform + 157
    10  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2036a6f1 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 41
    11  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff20369abe __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 607
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff20363ff8 __CFRunLoopRun + 2578
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff20363103 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 567
    14  GraphicsServices                    0x00007fff2c851cd3 GSEventRunModal + 139
    15  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff24ffbe63 -[UIApplication _run] + 928
    16  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff25000a53 UIApplicationMain + 101
```

What's the problem? How can I fix that?

**Update:**

I tried to clear the collectionView and reload data on `prepareForReuse`. This fixed the above exception. But I got a warning about clearing collectionView.dropDelegate in the middle of a drag/drop interaction and cells behavior wasn't correct.

What really works for me is to not reuse cells for the board's column with different indexes. So I register the column's cell with different identifiers for each index path (usually the board has from 3 to 5 columns).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by implementing `prepareForReuse` method and reset the collectionView.

```
    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        collectionView.dataSource = nil
        collectionView.delegate = nil
        collectionView.dragDelegate = nil
        collectionView.dropDelegate = nil
        collectionView.reloadData()
    }
```